# Does iBooks support localStorage in the ePUB format?

Tags: local-storage, epub, ibooks

I'm implementing a JavaScript program in the ePUB XML-based digital book format which uses localStorage.

I'm confusing about the situation whether iBooks supports localStorage.

Some version supports, some not.

Answer (score 3):

iBooks HTML widgets do support localStorage, and will persist data across opening of the book (and across widgets). iBooks itself is mostly inconsistent when it comes to supporting localStorage -- various updates have broken it, such that you can't rely on its working across all versions.

Comment: does what you're saying apply to compliant flowing and fixed epub2/3s in iBooks, or just to iBooks Author in iBooks?

Comment: For the most part, I've been able to get localStorage in regular EPUB working, but it's been finicky so I haven't relied on it across all iBooks versions.